# What is wlConcatenatedUserHead0.js?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

[I am facing this issue in mfp 7. See the attached image for better clarification.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q8Xr.png)

Comment: Instead of this, there should be name of controller.js of that respective page. Earlier it was working fine but now, I am facing issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you chose to concat and minify your web resources? Sure looks like that. 
You should try without it.
And do note that MFP 7.0 is out of support now.

Comment: No, I didn't minify any of my file. This issue is intermittent.

Comment: Do you see this only if you run in mobile browser environment?

Comment: I see this only when i use desktop environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"wlconcatenatedbody0.js" gets created when you chose to concatenate your JS files. This is a choice you make as part of your build process. The configuration to do this, is enabled via build-settings.xml. Concatenation of JS files is not on by default in Desktop browser environment.

Refer to the steps and details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_concatenation.html).

This does not cause runtime issues, but if there is a problem, troubleshooting becomes hard. If you do not wish to have concatenation on, you should modify the settings accordingly.